# How best should one duplicate the last element of an array?

Tags: c#-4.0

Here's my rather clumsy solution:

```
   // Duplicate last element 
   { 
          List<PointF> t; 
          t = tiles.ToList(); 
          t.Add(tiles.LastOrDefault()); 
          tiles = t.ToArray(); 
   }
```

The strange fact that .Add does not return the list means one statement is forced to be four.

What's a better e.g. more concise way? Thanks.

Comment: Why not just use an Arraylist?

Comment: `LastOrDefault()` will add `null` to your list if `tiles` is empty, it's better to just check for `tiles.Any()` and use `tiles.First()` if it's not empty

Comment: Actually, I didn't notice that `PointF` is a struct, so `FirstOrDefault` will add the (0;0) to your array if it's empty in the first place, is it the desired logic?

Comment: @Dyppl: sorry but i dont follow with the 2011?. what difference should it make what year or version it is?

Comment: @Gleeb: there is no reason to use `ArrayList` when targeting .NET 2.0 or higher. Generic collections (namely `List<T>`) provide the same functionality while providing type safety and improved performance. MSDN article on `ArrayList` doesn't say it's obsolete or deprecated, but effectively it is: http://csharpindepth.com/ViewNote.aspx?NoteID=19 Using `ArrayList` for new code doesn't make any sense unless you are targeting .NET 1.1, and `List<T>` is just plain better for virtually any use case. So what I meant was "It's 2011 and .NET 2.0 with generics has been around for half a decade now".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm finding your example difficult to follow... let me know if this makes sense.

```
var strings = new[] { "Item 1", "Item 2" };
strings = strings.Concat(new[] { strings.LastOrDefault() }).ToArray();
```

This example takes an array and duplicates the last item.

In your case it looks like `tiles` is an array of `PointF`. If you want to duplicate the last element all you have to do is:

```
tiles = tiles.Concat(new[] { tiles.LastOrDefault() }).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?
it will duplicate your last element what ever it is.
it covers the endcase of an empty array

```
ArrayList<PointF> t;
t = tiles.toList();
if (t.size() ==0){
//something else or nothing
}else{
t.add(new PointF(t.at(t.size()-1))); 
//i am not a C# programmer and i dont even have VS so it could be get() or something
tiles = t.toArray();
}
```